# Tic Tac Toe function not defining variable correctly

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm building a Tic Tac Toe game as practice for an intro-to-Python course I'm taking on Udemy.  I have a series of functions built right now but I can't get two of them to work together.  When I run these two functions I get an error saying the `first_player` is undefined.  However, `first_player` is defined in the first function.  Does anyone know why Python won't recognize what `first_player` is in the second function?

If these functions work correctly I'd expect it to as the first player if he/she wants to be X's or O's and then have Python assign X's or O's to player 1 and player 1.

In the `choose_first player()` I've tried printing out the `first_player` variable and it prints correctly.

The code I'm using is below:

```
#Randomly chooses which player goes first.
def choose_first_player():
    import random
    first_player = (str(random.randint(1,2)))

    if first_player == '1':
        print("\nPlayer " +first_player+ " goes first.")
    if first_player == '2':
        print("\nPlayer " +first_player+ " goes first.")

choose_first_player()

#Asks first_player if they want to be X's or O's.
def player_input():

    marker = ''

    while marker != 'X' and marker != 'O':
        marker = input("\nPlayer" +first_player+ " , do you want to be X's or O's?  Please enter X or O: ").upper()

    player1 = marker

    if player1 == 'X':
        player2 = 'O'
    else:
        player2 = 'X'
        player1 = 'O'

    print("\nPlayer 1 is: " + player1)
    print("Player 2 is: " + player2)
    return(player1,player2)

player_input()
```

Comment: You should read that link and some more about the [scope of variables in Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+variable+scope). Your problem is that the `first_player` is defined inside `choose_first_player()` and therefore isn't accessible elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it does answer my question, thanks!  I guess when I was trying to google an answer I didn't know I was looking for "Scope".  That explains everything.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the variable of another function. (or you have to define it as a global variable)

`choose_first_player` can return the value of `first_player` and then you can pass it to the other function.

And do something like this :

```
def choose_first_player():
    ...
    return first_player

first_player = choose_first_player()

... 

def player_input(first_player):
  ...

player_input(first_player)
```

Here you can read more on [python scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

Comment: This question is asked a thousand times. Please don't answer duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for code and the link.  They both helped explain things.  I didn't know I was looking for a "scope" problem when I started googling this.  Thanks again.